# How to get string between string in php

Tags: php

i have string look like this:

```
$str='root.path.to.nameClass.*';
```

now, i want get 'nameClass', this my code:

```
$tmp=explode('.',$str);
return $tmp[count($tmp)-2];
```

it really working, but i don't want using explode, what is best solution?

Comment: Why don't you want to use explode ? It looks like it's fine.

Comment: I would suggest to use `array_slice` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) instead of array accessing by index: `return array_slice($tmp, -2, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp`s for this also:

```
if (preg_match("/^.*\.(.+)\.\*$/", chop($str), $parts))
  echo "My nameClass is: " . $parts[1] . "\n";
```